# How to delete 1 row by 2 variables in sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table called `transactions` in sqlite:

```
gun | user1
gun | user1
gun | user1
medkit | user1
gun | user2
medkit | user2
```

etc

I want to remove only 1 row `gun | user1`

So i made a SQL request: `cursor.execute('DELETE FROM transactions WHERE username =:username AND item_name=:item_name LIMIT 1',{'username':username,'item_name':item_name})`

Figured out, that I have problems with `SQLITE ENABLE UPDATE DELETE LIMIT`, which i am to dumb to install.

After some googling i figured out, that I can do something like this:

```
cursor.execute('''DELETE FROM transactions
               WHERE username in 
               (SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE username=:username AND item_name=:item_name LIMIT 1)
               ''',{'username':username,'item_name':item_name})
```

but sql gives me an error: `sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1`

so i am giving up googling, cause I am confused. help!

---

full code, if needed:

```
def remove_item(self, username,item_name):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db") 
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        #cursor.execute('DELETE FROM transactions WHERE username =:username AND item_name=:item_name LIMIT 1',{'username':username,'item_name':item_name})
        cursor.execute('''DELETE FROM transactions
                        WHERE username in 
                        (SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE username=:username AND item_name=:item_name LIMIT 1)
                        ''',{'username':username,'item_name':item_name})
        conn.commit()
        print(f'player.py >> Item {item_name} removed from {username}')
```

*P.S: I am newbie in SQL and Python, so... Don't kill me :D*

Comment: Yeah, update limit support requires first building a custom version of the sqlite3.c amalgamation from the original source, and then compiling that with a specific option enabled. It's only really practical when using it in C or C++ programs where you have that level of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.execute('''DELETE FROM transactions
               WHERE username in 
               (SELECT username FROM transactions WHERE username=:username AND item_name=:item_name LIMIT 1)
               ''',{'username':username,'item_name':item_name})
```

Will return just the one column **username** from the subquery **BUT** that will then delete all rows that have the extracted username from the subquery.

What you could do is :-

```
cursor.execute('''DELETE FROM transactions
               WHERE rowid = 
               (SELECT rowid FROM transactions WHERE username=:username AND item_name=:item_name LIMIT 1)
               ''',{'username':username,'item_name':item_name})
```

But only if the table has not been defined using the WITHOUT ROWID clause.

**rowid** is a special, normally hidden column, that uniquely identifies a row and thus extracting the **[rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)** and using that in the WHERE clause will identify that specific row.

Note that in theory any of the rows that match the item_name and username could be deleted not necessarily the first. Really you should use an ORDER BY clause to ensure that the first row is the expected row. However, the above will likely work as the order, as none is specified, will likely be according to the **rowid** as that would be the index used.

As you have no useful index you could use rowid as for the ORDER (rowid will typically be as per the insert order i.e. the first insert would have a rowid of 1, then likely 2 and 3 and so on). As such the more correct code could be :-

```
cursor.execute('''DELETE FROM transactions
               WHERE rowid = 
               (SELECT rowid FROM transactions WHERE username=:username AND item_name=:item_name ORDER BY rowid LIMIT 1)
               ''',{'username':username,'item_name':item_name})
```